# Elasticsearch match list against field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list, array or whichever language you are familiar. E.g. names : `["John","Bas","Peter"]` and I want to query the `name` field if it matches one of those names.

One way is with OR Filter. e.g.

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "or" : [
                {
                    "term" : { "name" : "John" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "name" : "Bas" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "name" : "Peter" }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any fancier way? Better if it's a query than a filter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms": {
          "name": ["John","Bas","Peter"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which Elasticsearch rewrites as if you hat used this one

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "John"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "Bas"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "Peter"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When using a boolean filter, most of the time, it is better to use the `bool` filter than `and` or `or`. The reason is explained on the Elasticsearch blog: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

Comment: Thanks, so [terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) is what I needed. I put in the query in my case

Comment: `filtered` is now deprecated, see Erfan's answer

Answer (score 23):

As I tried the `filtered` query I got `no [query] registered for [filtered]`, based on [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered) it seems the filtered query has been deprecated and removed in ES 5.0. So I provide using:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "name": ["John","Bas","Peter"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example query = filter by keyword and a list of values

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "fguid": "9bbfe844-44ad-4626-a6a5-ea4bad3a7bfb.pdf"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "page": [
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```