# Python Elasticsearch DSL query value from a list

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I am using Python's Elasticsearch DSL package:
http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_dsl.html

My sample elasticsearch entry looks like:

```
{
  "_index" : "users",
  "_type" : "player",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 5,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"doc": {"weight": 92, "height": 184, "gender": "male", "firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "age": 31, "country": "France"}}
```

and I'm trying to fetch all entries that `firstname = "John*"` country in the list of `[France, Australia]`. Here's my code:

```
firstname = 'John'
s = Search(index='users').using(elasticsearch)
must = [
  {'match': {'doc.firstname': {'query': firstname + '*', 'boost': 2}}},
  {'terms': {'doc.country': [u'France', u'Australia']}}]

s = s.query(Q('bool', must=must))
response = s.execute()
```

it returns empty results, what am I doing wrong? I'm using the suggestion from here:
[Elasticsearch match list against field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777700/elasticsearch-match-list-against-field)

I'm new to Elasticsearch, still a little confused with where we use query vs filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the should param for this instead:

```
firstname = 'John'
s = Search(index='users').using(elasticsearch)
must = [
  {'match': {'doc.firstname': {'query': firstname + '*', 'boost': 2}}}]

should = []
for country in countries:
  should.append({'match': {'doc.country': country}})

s = s.query(Q('bool', must=must, should=should, minimum_should_match=1))
response = s.execute()
```