# elasticsearch date range filter error 'no [query] registered for [filtered]'

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range, jquery-filter

I need to get result from elasticsearch using filter (date range)

this is my query,

```
'{
    "sort" : [{ "bytes" : {"order" : "desc"}}],
    "query": {
              "filtered": {
                   "query": { "match_all": {} },
                       "filter": {
                           "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "gte": "2017-11-07T00:00:01Z",
                                    "lte": "2017-11-12T00:00:01Z"
                                 }
                            }
                       }
                  }
            }
 }'
```

when i run this query, i got an error 'no [query] registered for [filtered]'.
I am following the format given in the filtered query documentation on the elasticsearch page.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/_executing_filters.html

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? You're looking at the documentation for ES 1.4, but are you really using 1.4? If not, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521602/4604579

Comment: "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.2",
  },
i think, i have checked v. 1.4 documentation.

Comment: Then you have your answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you val. i created that query as in v.5.6 documentation. but it seems not working correctly. the output was not correct. i just want to filter values by date range and sort it. i'm new for elasticsearch.

Comment: this is my query. any error there?

Comment: '{    
    "query":{
          "bool":{
              must": {"match_all":{}},
                    "filter": {
                        "range": {
                             "@timestamp":{
                                   "gte": "2017-11-07T00:00:01Z",
                                    "lte": "2017-11-12T00:00:01Z"
                                }
                          }
                   }
            }    
                            },
                        "sort" : { "bytes" : {"order" : "desc"}}    
                        }'

Comment: You're simply missing a double quote before `must`

Comment: ohh, i'm paste above code section and backspace, that's why its missing double quote. but in my code its there. this query is working. there is a output, but it not in the date range that i specified. you have any idea?

Comment: How do you send your query to ES? Update your question with all the relevant info

Answer (score 1):

the syntax was changed for ES 5.0, and The `filtered` query is replaced by the `bool` query. what you have to **change is, the two bellow line**

```
      "filtered": {
           "query": { "match_all": {} },
```

**By**

```
"bool" : {
   "must" : {  "match_all": {} },
}
```