# Convert elastic search terms filter to 5.6

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I was using the below query to find out student's details from an elastic search index ( ES Version 2.6 ). Multiple student IDs (max 50 Nos.) were passed to this query so that it brings out the details

{
      "size": 5000,
      "_source": false,
      "fields": ["student_name","age", "mobile","pincode","library_id"],
      "query": {
          "filtered": {
              "query": {
                  "bool": {
                      "must": [
                            {
                                "terms": {"student_id": ['124,563,222']}
                            }
                        ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}

This is not working in ES 5.6 . Could someone help me understand how to translate this to version 5.6 ? Any useful links also would be fine. Thanks

Comment: this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered/40521602#40521602

Comment: Thanks. But this is a different use case.

Comment: No that's the same issue, `filtered` query have been removed in ES 5 so you can simply move the `bool` query to the top-level.

Comment: Ohk. Will check it out. Thanks @Val