# Symfony and Elastic search upgrade

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I have to upgrade one of my customer's web site from Symfony 2.8/Elastic Search 1.7/FOS\elastica-bundle" 3.2 to 3.4/6.2/5.0.3.

I have made a copy of the existing web site on a brand new server with Elastic Search 6.2 installed.

I have read many about this and understood I have to rewrite the Bundle that managed Elastic queries because a lot of methods are outdated, specially DSL filters.

Di you have any idea of what the following code (in the Bundle controller) would become in ES 6.2 :

```
$query = $request->query->get("query","");       
$finder = $this->container->get("fos_elastica.finder.scls_concert.concert");
$queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
$esTextQuery = $queryBuilder->query()->query_string($query);
$esDateFilter = $queryBuilder->filter()->range('date_start',array('gte' => (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp()));

$esQuery = $queryBuilder->query()->filtered($esTextQuery,$esDateFilter);
$result = $finder->findPaginated($esQuery,["size" => 5]);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in the above code is that the [`filtered` query is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered/40521602#40521602) and needs to be replaced by `bool`:

So I think, you can do something along these lines:

```
$esDateFilter = new Range( 'date_start', array('gte' => (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp()) );

$esQuery = new BoolQuery();
$esQuery->addMust($esTextQuery);
$esQuery->addFilter($esDateFilter);
$result = $finder->findPaginated($esQuery,["size" => 5]);
```

Comment: I'm afraid the following line is also wrong as DSL filter is not supported anymore : $esDateFilter = $queryBuilder->filter()->range('date_start',array('gte' => (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp()));

Comment: Try simply removing `filter()`, see my updated answer

Comment: Not working, still getting "DSL "filter" not supported " error. I alsor replace $bool with $esQuery.

Comment: Looks better with the following code : $esDateFilter = new Range(
            'date_start',
            array('gte' => (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp())
            );

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Val, I really appreciate it !