# Passing _type in Query parameter vs in URL in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query an elastic search cluster. 
The index name is `titles` and _type is `title`. When I put the type in the request URL, the filtering works as expected:

```
POST http://esendpoint.com/titles/title/_search?
```

The body:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {

        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {  "term" : {"_docTitleIds" : "65d-7ab2-41d4-a928-300accfc8ab7"}}
          ]
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

However if I add the _type title in the query body, and not in the URL I get all results under the index `titles`. But when used in the URL, I get results only from the type `title`

`POST http://esendpoint.com/titles/_search`

The body:

```
"query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {

            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {  "term" : {"_type" : "title"}},
                {  "term" : {"_docTitleIds" : "65d-7ab2-41d4-a928-300accfc8ab7"}}
              ]
            }
          }

        }
      }
```

I'm not able to follow why this is happening.

Comment: You should tell what error you're getting. Note that you're missing a comma after the `_type` constraint.

Comment: @Val Sorry, I missed out the comma. I updated the question. I don't get an exception, but I get results from the entire index rather the specific type like how it is when passed via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `filter` (AND) instead of `should` (OR):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_type": "title"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "_docTitleIds": "65d-7ab2-41d4-a928-300accfc8ab7"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query below is for ES 2 and later:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_type": "title"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_docTitleIds": "65d-7ab2-41d4-a928-300accfc8ab7"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the exception:
`SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures`

Comment: Also in my example I use filtered instead of filter and have query inside filtered. Maybe that is an issue?

Comment: I've elastic search 1.7.1 if it matters. The error cause is `bool query does not support [filter]`

Comment: I've updated my answer to match 1.7.1 but be aware [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered/40521602#40521602) when you migrate to a more recent version.