# How do I create an “In” Condition filter using elasticsearch-dsl-py?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl

The query below is what I would like to construct using elasticsearch-dsl-py, but I do not know how to do it.

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "status": "a"
              },
              "term": {
                "status": "b"
              },
              "term": {
                "status": "c"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to execute a query like below in SQL format

```
select * from my_index where status in ("a","b","c")
```

Using elasticsearch-dsl-py, this is as close as I can get, but it is not the same.

```
class MyIndex(Document):

    status = Keyword() / Text()
    
    

MyIndex.search().filter('should', status=["a","b","c"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing this is by using the `terms` query with an array as each array element is implicitly ORed. Also, I'm not sure which version of ES you're running, but just know that [`filtered` has been replaced by `bool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered/40521602#40521602) a long time ago in version 5. So your query can be rewritten like this:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
         "terms": {
           "status": ["a", "b", "c"]
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using `elasticsearch-dsl-py`, this translates to:

```
s = Search()
s = s.filter('terms', status=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: This answer worked for me but I fail to see the difference with `{"query": {"terms": {"status": ["a", "b", "c"]}}}`, could you tell please?

Comment: @ciurlaro not sure what you mean

Comment: is there any logical difference between the query you wrote and the one that I wrote? I was wondering why you put also put `bool` and `filter`

Comment: The difference is that without `bool/filter`, scoring kicks in and when you're doing exact matching like is the case in this question, it's useless and increases the response time unnecessarily

Comment: That was a clever observation. Thanks.