# How to specific day of month search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

what i am doing now is get all data and filter the "day of Month" like 2020-01-05, 2020-02-05
in pandas,

how can i search specific Day of Month in Elasticsearch?

my doc is something like below

```
{
    "took": 80,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1508,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_data",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "SlR42nYBlaUrIoJsVOv6",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "timestamp": 1609983082524,
                    "timestampstring": "2021-01-07 09:31:22.524",
                    "oneNetDevieId": "624232444",
                    "type": "data"
                },
                "sort": [
                    2609983082524
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_data",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "6FRL2nYBlaUrIoJsAuba",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
```

...

I have try something like

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.timestampstring.date.dayOfMonth == 5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "script": {
              "script": "doc._source.timestampstring.date.dayOfMonth == 5"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and it shows error
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "unknown query [filtered]",
"line": 5,
"col": 17

or do i need to mapping?thanks

Edited update:

```
i got the new error:
  "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "doc['timestamp'].value.getDayOfMonth() == 5",
                        "                      ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "doc['timestamp'].value.getDayOfMonth() == 5",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "position": {
                        "offset": 22,
                        "start": 0,
                        "end": 43
                    },
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "dynamic method [java.lang.Long, getDayOfMonth/0] not found"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered/40521602#40521602 (hint: `filtered` needs to be replaced by `bool`)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Val, `filtered` is replaced by [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). You need to modify your query as shown below

Adding a working example with index mapping, data, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestampstring": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
   "timestampstring": "2020-11-06 15:22:58.537"
}
{
   "timestampstring": "2020-11-05 21:21:51.655"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
       "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "doc['timestampstring'].value.getDayOfMonth() == 5",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65607193",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "timestampstring": "2020-11-05 21:21:51.655"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: should  i use timestamp or timestampstring ?
since timestampstring seems not supported in ES

Comment: @ManManYu you need to define the mapping for the field. Please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: thanks but it seems that the field "timestamp": 1609983082524,
match the date format "epoch_millis" in ES, so i would like if i can use this to do query so i dont need to do mapping, but i still got an error i post in edit updated

Comment: @ManManYu which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: version  6.8 the @ someone is not working today ..weird

Comment: i doubt if i need to convert the timestamp into "milliSinceEpochString"....